# Adding elements to top and bottom of UITable View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am new to objective C. I have a small app where I have used a UITableviewcontroller(TVC). I need to add four elements.,label and button above TVC and a label and button below TVC. But it is allowing only to add 2 elements., one above TVC and other below TVC. Also added element is occupying the entire width of screen. Can I overcome this restriction???

Answer (score 0):

Customize the table view cell – instead of using the default style of table view cell.

this link is helpful you with sample project

http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These two are tableview properties.

```
tableHeaderView
tableFooterView
```

By using the above properties you can show your own custom view on top / bottom of table view.

sample code

```
[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:yourHeaderView];
[self.tableView setTableFooterView:yourFooterView];
```

Write this code in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Hello Ram., So every thing we need to do is Programmatical here., and nothing to do in utilities right?

Comment: how u r creating the uivew using xibs or coding.

Comment: By Dragging the controllers from the object library in utilities Section ( Xcode-5).

Comment: Do you have any knowledge on custom uiview creating using xib (Dragging).

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewController is kind of a screwed up class, in my opinion. A UITableViewController can only manage a table view, and nothing else. If you want a more complex layout where you have a table view on part of the screen, and then other view objects elsewhere, you can't do that with a UITableViewController.

However, with iOS 6 and later, there is a pretty easy solution.

You can embed a UITableViewController as a child view controller of another view controller.

What you do is to create a parent view controller with everything you need. Then you create a container view on your parent view controller and size it to contain your table view. Then you create a separate scene in your storyboard that defines a table view controller. Finally, you control-drag from your container view to your UITableViewController, and create an embed segue.

I have a project on github that demonstrates this technique:

[**Demo project using `UITableViewController`s as child view controllers**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/test)